Are the concepts of omniscience and omnipotence contradictory?
Theistic religions believe in a God or Gods.
Do religions that claim their God is omniscient and omnipotent face a contradiction in this conception?
I'll explain my reasoning.
If God is omniscient, he knows everything.
If God is omnipotent, he is all powerful.
If God knows everything he knows every action of his creation and the actions of himself?
If God knows how he will act does God have free will?
If God is omnipotent, can God take an action that is not determined by God's omniscience?
If God cannot, is God omnipotent?
Ergo
Is God's omniscience and omnipotence a contradiction?
I ask this question using a determination of a definition of all knowing, and all-powerful as meaning exactly that.
Do not dismiss this question as it has no sound arguments anywhere else in this forum.
With a side note I believe, and have faith contrary to the conclusion of the question.

@benrg That question is of a similar veign but is over 13 years old. Do you not think that new users of this site would benefit from this question. That question did not come up as similar example as iformed mine.

You want to read The Euthyphro Trilemma and Theodicy.

Yes, very.
You explained it well; there's no logical way to circumvent the issues that the two concepts pose. They would necessarily contradict each other if held by one being at once.
This is doubly so because, as pointed out in comments on this thread, each concept is itself logically impossible.

Thanks for your answer. How is omniscience self defeating? This is not a challenge to disparage your answer its a genuine question. Man's pursuit is to gain knowledge of the unknown presumably to a limit that is itself non contradictory.

Of course! A truly omniscient being would necessarily know the outcome of paradoxical scenarios, which are of course impossible by nature. To keep the example close to this post, an all-knowing being would know if an omnipotent being could create a burrito so large that even they couldn't eat it.

Is there any reason for absolute beings to follow finite logic or ability? That this is not the case is the standard objection brought forward by Abrahamic theists.

@PhilipKlöcking: As I've said before, if we don't have logic available, then smagigfizzle. I've never seen a theist reply to this, and I doubt that they can; you can't throw away "if" and "then" and "and" and hope that everything still comes together neatly. Also, since spacetime itself gives a partial order, we have a natural example of a deductive system in our physics; logic isn't that artificial.

@PhilipKlöcking Corbin is correct here. Claiming that something you cannot prove wasn't made up has powers beyond physics and logic is not compelling, and not worth the effort in arguing against.

Omniscience and omnipotence together entail a contradiction because omnipotence alone entails a contradiction. Can an omnipotent entity create an object so hard he, himself, cannot break it? Any answer entails a contradiction.
Terms that are all-encompassing are further problematic because their scope cannot even be modified to a context where they make sense, as then they won’t be all-encompassing (apply in every context). This makes such terms stubborn even to variations of meaning.

Why does the contradiction of omnipotence in your example have any bearing to the contradiction of omniscience and omnipotence in my question, they are completely unrelated?

@8Mad0Manc8 If it is contradictory for an entity to be omnipotent, it is contradictory for an entity to be both omnipotent and omniscient.

I dont think the argument you are proposing about omnipotence is sound its the defacto response to the question of omnipotence. You are right that if one of these concepts is wrong or untrue than you can hardly argue that one and the other are true. Boolean logic and all.

@8Mad0Manc8 Then in what way is it unsound? If an entity is all-powerful, can it create an object it cannot break?

God can do anything other than what you would consider a contradiction? This falls within the definition of omnipotence, even within the definition I wanted to restrict my question too. The contradiction you have stated in omnipotence as far as I know is difficult to challenge other than how I have.
